# Scroll 100's of attribute sets when creating a new product

Tags: attribute-set

I have to create 100's of different attribute sets for our products. To filter all these products I use:

`first filter: scope area second filter: application`

So, when I have to create a new product, I have to scroll an endless number of attribute sets.

The current status in Magento is:

```
1 => select => Attribute Set
2 => select => Product type
```

My Idea is, to add two selection fields before like:

```
1 => select => Scope area
2 => select => Select Application
3 => select => Attribute Set
4 => select => Product type
```

I would be realy glad, if someone could help me to solve this problem.

PS: When I have posted the first time (about 2 month ago), a user (name forgotten) has edited my post concerning to the english grammar. Therefore  I want to appologize in advance if I made some mistakes. Nevertheless I hope, that my english is clear enough. :-)